# Solving a coupled system of inequalities over integers

Tags: inequalities

! tried to solve $ \frac{999999}{1000000}<a+\sqrt{2} b\land a+\sqrt{2} b<1$ over the integers through

```
Reduce[999999/1000000 < a + Sqrt[2]* b && a + Sqrt[2]*b < 1, {a,b}, Integers]
*(a|b)∈ Integers&&(999999 - 1000000 a)/(1000000 Sqrt[2])<b<(1 - a)/Sqrt[2]*
```

, but the answer is not constructive. The [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) command instantly fails. The command

```
NMaximize[{1,999999/1000000 < a + Sqrt[2]* b && a + Sqrt[2]* b < 1 && {a,b}∈ Integers}, {a, b}]
```

is running without any response  for hours. The solutions exist in view of

```
999999/1000009 < a + Sqrt[2]*b&&a + Sqrt[2]*b < 1 /.{a-> -12345606202, b->8729661864}
*True*
```

Comment: There are infinitely many such pairs and you will not describe constructively solutions unless you suplement conditions on solutions. This is a nice example what `Reduce` can do.

Comment: @Artes: Can you ground your statementss? TIA.

Comment: I find it is obvious nevertheless one has to work out a satisfactory answer in a way comprehensible for others. .

Comment: @Artes: Thank you for your personal opinions. I prefer arguments. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Artes: Can you kindly present a solution of the system under consideration which differs from {a-> -12345606202, b->8729661864}? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 - The inequality used to verify `{a -> -12345606202, b -> 8729661864}` as a solution is not the same inequality as that appearing in the `Reduce`. These values do not satisfy the inequalities in the `Reduce`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Thank you for your valuable comment. These numbers found by NMaximize satisfy 99999/100000 < a + Sqrt[2]*b && 
  a + Sqrt[2]*b < 1. Sorry for the bad paste and copying. I'll try to be more careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can find solutions to this using rational approximations for the Sqrt[2].  For example, using

```
s40 = Last[Convergents[Sqrt[2], 40]]
(* 1023286908188737/723573111879672 *)

s41 = Last[Convergents[Sqrt[2], 41]]
(* 2470433131948081/1746860020068409 *)
```

we get two accurate approximations, one either side of `Sqrt[2]`

```
s40 > Sqrt[2] > s41
(* True *)
```

Given the exact inequality

```
ineqexact = 
  999999/1000000 < a + Sqrt[2]*b && a + Sqrt[2]*b < 1;
```

We can define 4 inequalities such that any solution will be a solution of the exact inequality

```
ineqapprox = (ineqexact /. Sqrt[2] -> s40) && (ineqexact /. Sqrt[2] -> s41);
```

We can find a solution

```
instance = FindInstance[ineqapprox, {a, b}, Integers]
(* {{a -> -2103168819944748, b -> 1487164934563041}} *)
```

and verify it

```
ineqexact /. instance
(* {True} *)
```

I presume that using progressively more accurate approximations one could find many more.

Comment: Thank you. I accept your answer. It should be noticed that FindInstance[ineqapprox, {a, b}, Integers, 3] performs SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure] on my comp.

Comment: @user64494 MemoryAllocationFailure sounds like you've run out of memory.  Perhaps you can monitor memory usage?

Comment: No, the RAM of my comp does not exhaust.